# Checkboxes - Macro not working for conditional formatting to uncheck all boxes

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am making a macro to add a new block of columns for every day in a google sheet. One column is populated with checkboxes which will be clicked by a user to mark the task as complete.

However, I have encountered serious difficulty when trying to copy and paste a new column containing unchecked checkboxes. The checkboxes do not appear at all and are somehow not recorded in the macro.

I also couldn't find a way to conditionally uncheck or check all the checkboxes in a column at once e.g. by the formula `=TRUE(A2:A50)` to check them and `=FALSE(A2:A50)` to uncheck them as it is giving an error.

Am I missing something or have I found a flaw in Google Sheets' checkbox system?

[image]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54954993/5632629

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52375604/5632629